# Exceeding guaranteed memory write cycles

Tags: stm32, flash

I have an STM32 MCU with integrated flash that has a specified endurance of 10'000 write cycles. What exactly is the risk if I exceed this number during my products lifetime? My understanding is that the 10'000 cycles are "guaranteed" by the manufacturer but what is the error rate beyond that? Can I expect to reach 20'000 in most cases or is the flash likely to fail after 11'000 cycles?

Comment: No, the flash is not going to fall of a cliff and die if you exceed the 10,000 write cycle guarantee. You will start to see more bad bits.  Whether your application can tolerate this depends on how you are going to manage things like bad blocks; are you doing any error detection/correction. etc.

Comment: Note that if you just need to store a small amount of information you can use a page of flash as a circular buffer, storing the data in a different spot each time.  Erase the page when its full and start again.  This can extend your 10,000 writes into possibly millions of writes.

Comment: Which exact STM32 model? They all might have different specs in which conditions it will guarantee 10000 write cycles.

Comment: It's an STM32L4. The ring buffer approach is what came to my mind as well, I just wanted to know whether it is really needed or if we're talking about factor 2-3 of safety margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, characterize how the flash fails. Yes, you yourself have to get several of those chips and run some test code on them that exercises the flash the way the product would and see what happens. Otherwise you're just guessing, and we can't answer this any better than you can by doing real work with real chips.

Once the failure modes are characterized, you need to develop some data encoding that will gracefully deal with errors - at the very least it must detect errors, but it should ideally also be able to correct them. You don't need complex ECC schemes - sometimes just writing the same data in a couple of copies is enough.

Your question is also very general. It all depends on how you map your data writes into the flash cells. If you spread the writes across many cells, and the amount of data saved is small - a few bytes - then at the cost of just a couple of flash pages you can get effective endurances of millions of write cycles. The question is very much incomplete without such details!